# Global catch for submit forms in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: vuex, vue.js, vuejs2

I have many forms in my app that have repetitive actions...

```
<form @submit.prevent="save" novalidate 
   ...
```

And save method ..

```
save () {
   ...
   return this.saveEvent(payload)
      .then(() => { self.resetForm() })
      .catch(resp => { 
         if (resp.status === 400) {   
           // verry repetitive task!!
         }
      })
```

Notice the `.catch(resp => { ... })`

In all forms in my app, I need to put this catch to handle form fields and server response.

So, my question is, how to handle repetitive catch tasks in Vue.js?
How to create a directive or component and all my forms will use the component that will handle server response and form fields in one place only.

#### Tried

I create a directive called `v-catch-errors`

```
<form @submit.prevent="save" novalidate v-catch-errors
   ...
```

But, how to handle ajax actions in this directive?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @SadoOgie I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

.then() and .catch() are both functions, so I would just create a new method with your repetitive code. Something like:

```
methods: {
  save () {
    var self = this
    return this.saveEvent(payload)
      .then(() => { self.resetForm() })
      .catch(resp => { 
        if (resp.status === 400) {
          self.repetitiveTask()
        }
      })
  },
  repetitiveTask () {
    // verry repetitive task!!
  }
}
```

I did `var self = this` so you can call the `repetitiveTask()` method in a different scope.